# How to identify if some rows start with #txt?

Tags: c#

I have a text file `installer_input.txt` where after many rows I have some rows that start with `product.` or `#product.`.

I wanna verify when I have first row who starts with `#product.` and if all rows after that who contains `product.` and starts with `#` it's like `#product.` then check all items from `checkedListBox2`.

On this way I tried this code :

```
linesInsTemp.Where(x => x.Contains("product.") )
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(item =>
                {                      
                    for (int i = 0; i < this.checkedListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        this.checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                    }
                    var index = this.checkedListBox2.Items.IndexOf(item);
                    if (index >= 0)
                        this.checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(index, true);
                });
```

But here when I have just `product.` without `#` then check the box.

In installer_input.ini I have something like this :

```
Many rows of text





#product.name1
#product.name2
...
#product.nameN

Rows with text
```

If all rows `product.name` have # in front then check all boxes. How I can do this ?

Comment: Is the inconsistent spelling of `product` intentional? It's hard to know of it's part of the problem in question or not.

Comment: The idea is: when I have All the rows who contains #product.name then check all checkBoxes

Comment: Yes, but is there a difference between `product` and `prodact`? Or have you just misspelled in your question?

Comment: Yeah, it confused me aswell Tobbe. But I haven't edited it, cause I wasnt sure either.

Comment: Same here @Jannik, the user accepted the answer though so I guess it was just misspelled...? I guess we'll never know! :)

Comment: sorry, my mistake it's product, I edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [String.StartsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method should help you. You can rewrite your method as

```
linesInsTemp.Where(x =>x.StartsWith("#product.") )
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(item =>
               {                      
                    for (int i = 0; i < this.checkedListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        this.checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                    }
                    var index = this.checkedListBox2.Items.IndexOf(item);
                    if (index >= 0)
                        this.checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(index, true);
                });
```

---

UPDATE:
this regex will return `true` for all rows which started with #product/product/prodact/#prodact

```
linesInsTemp.Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, "^(#)?prod(u|a)ct[\\w\\W]*") )
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(function);
```

Comment: it's not what I want because, in my case If I have some rows who starts with "#product." and some who starts with "product."... where  I have "#product.name "  that chackBoxes remain unchecked. Just I case I Want to check all checkboxes I need to have all like this "#product.name " .... I hope you understand what I want to say ..

Comment: I already have your code but for uncheck the checkBoxes from checkedListBox2

Comment: what about regexp? Did you try to use pattern to detect rows you needed?

Comment: \\w - Matches any word character. 
\\W - Matches any non-word character.
[\\w\\W]* - none or any character of any symbol.